# How to delete record from data grid view with unique ID without deleting other record of the same unique ID?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

Time-in_Time-out GUI.

[image]

I have this image of my Time-in Time-out window. As you can see I want to delete a record of a certain employee in data grid view. I have this code.

```
conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)

conn.Open()

Try
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = conn

    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM timelogTB WHERE EmpNo='" & Me.dgvTimelog.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value & "'"

    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    If rowsAffected > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Record has been deleted!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Successful")
    Else
        MsgBox("Failed to delete records!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Deleting Failed...")
    End If

        cmd.Dispose()

Me.dgvTimelog.Rows.Remove(Me.dgvTimelog.CurrentRow)
conn.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

The problem is that when I click 1 record for a specific date, all of the record of that employee deleted also even from previous dates. I had try putting where clause but nothing happens. And also I want to put a conditional statement if the user really want to delete the record, I have this code.

```
If MsgBox("Do you really want to delete this record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Deleting...") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then 
MsgBox("Record deleted permanently!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Delete!")
```

but even if the user select No the record would still be deleted. Can anyone tell me what seems to be the problem. Thanks in advance!

This question is finished, try this code and it worked:
Private Sub btnDelete_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Try
            If MsgBox("Do you really want to delete this record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Deleting Record...") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                deleteRecords()
            Else
                MsgBox("Record not deleted!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Deleting Record...")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub deleteRecords()
        conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)

```
    conn.Open()

    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM timelogTB WHERE LogID=@LogID"

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LogID", SqlDbType.Int, 11, "LogID"))
        cmd.Parameters("@LogID").Value = dgvTimelog.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If rowsAffected > 0 Then

            MsgBox("Record deleted permanently!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Delete!")

        End If

        cmd.Dispose()

        Me.dgvTimelog.Rows.Remove(Me.dgvTimelog.CurrentRow)

        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Because the ID you're using is *not* unique.  `WHERE EmpNo=` means exactly what it says.  Where the employee number equals the given value.  If more than one record has that value, then it is not unique.  Do you have some way of *uniquely* identifying the record you want to delete?  Such as a primary key on the table?

Comment: I suspect that `EmpNo` uniquely identifes employes (???) but **not** time records.  And for the love of Tony the Pony, dont build SQL like that - use SQL parameters.  You are also burning connections.

Comment: ...yup - you want to delete `LogId` using `Cells(0).Value`,  You are also treating it like a string, but it appears to be an int (another reason to use SQL params)

Comment: @David, the EmpNo is a FK and LogID is PK which is auto increment.

Comment: @AtanHokage04: If LogID is the unique identifier, then you probably want to use LogID to uniquely identify the record.

Comment: @David, I use this code cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM timelogTB WHERE LogID=@LogID"
            ' '" & Me.dgvTimelog.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value & "'"

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LogID", SqlDbType.Int, 11, "LogID"))
            cmd.Parameters("@LogID").Value = dgvTimelog.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

Comment: I use the code above this comment and it worked. Thanks David and Plutonix.

Comment: @David, how about my other question sir. Even if I select No the record was still deleted.

Comment: All you're doing in that if statement is deciding whether or not to show a message box... That has nothing to do with whether your procedure executes...

Comment: @ZLK, how should I do it to stop executing the delete button if pressed No.

Comment: Add whether or not your code executes to your if statement.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Well, I don't know how your code currently works... But an example would be putting the part of the code that deletes the record in a sub/function and calling it ONLY on "yes". So like `if msgbox(...) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then call mySub and display messagebox end if`

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM timelogTB WHERE LogID=@LogID"
            ' '" & Me.dgvTimelog.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value & "'"

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LogID", SqlDbType.Int, 11, "LogID"))
            cmd.Parameters("@LogID").Value = dgvTimelog.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

Comment: above comment is my new command in deleting records in a table

Comment: make composite key with a combination of (logid + Empno)

Comment: Welcome to the SO community! Friendly reminder: please do not edit your answer into the question. Instead, you should ask the responsible comment poster(s) to post their answer suggestion, or post your own while crediting anyone necessary. Likewise, accepting the answer after it's posted will indicate to other users the question has been resolved.